# IFrame without scrollbars

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I tried to attach another website to my current page using iframe,
but it looks ugly with the scroll bars.

Is there any good alternative to it?
Any suggestion to achieve what I want, nicely attaching another webpage into my page without the annoyance of those scrollbars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `height` and `width` of iframe equal to your web page and if you want on a specific part of page then adding css `overflow : none` should help, and `frameborder:0` will clean up frame borders..

[Here](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/frames/_IFRAME_SCROLLING.html) is a good tutorial regarding scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Change the height and width accordingly
Try this

```
<iframe height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="500px" style="width: 500px; height: 100%;" src="http://example.com" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try to use a custom scrollbar like this one: [Link](http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had the same problem and this jquery plugin solved this problem perfectly.
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/iframe-auto-height